# Запятая перед союзом в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение

*Здравствуйте.*

*Есть такие строки: **«Оставьте больного: он болен давно(,) и нет ему этой болезни милее».***

*Интуитивно всё-таки хочется поставить указанную запятую, но у этого предложения вроде бы есть общая часть в начале...*

*Как быть?..*

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, если после И вторая причина. А на это очень похоже.